# MediaRecorder: java.lang.IllegalStateException at

Tags: android-mediarecorder

When I start the device and open my app everything works fine, but after use of another app on the device my app gave this error.

```
public void startRecorder(){

    // Check if user has given permission to record audio
    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO);
    if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO}, PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO);
        return;
    }
    if (mRecorder == null) {

        mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mRecorder.setOutputFile("/dev/null");
        mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);


        try {
            mRecorder.prepare();
            mRecorder.start();
        } catch (java.io.IOException ioe) {
            mRecorder = null;
            android.util.Log.e("[Monkey]", "IOException: " + android.util.Log.getStackTraceString(ioe));

        } catch (java.lang.SecurityException e) {
            mRecorder = null;
            android.util.Log.e("[Monkey]", "SecurityException: " + android.util.Log.getStackTraceString(e));
        }

    }


}
```

> 10-08 10:32:42.260 18121-18121/com.avatarmind.ipaldecibel E/###: JNI_MOTIONSERVICE LOAD
>   10-08 10:32:42.260 18121-18121/com.avatarmind.ipaldecibel E/###: MotionService Setup
>   10-08 10:32:42.526 18121-18121/com.avatarmind.ipaldecibel E/MediaRecorder: start failed: -38
>   10-08 10:32:42.529 18121-18121/com.avatarmind.ipaldecibel E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.avatarmind.ipaldecibel, PID: 18121
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.avatarmind.ipaldecibel/com.avatarmind.ipaldecibel.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3173)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3204)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2548)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1406)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5509)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:772)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:662)
>        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
>           at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)
>           at com.avatarmind.ipaldecibel.MainActivity.startRecorder(MainActivity.java:300)
>           at com.avatarmind.ipaldecibel.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:262)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1258)
>           at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6342)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3162)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3204) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2548) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1406) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5509) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:772) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:662)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that when resume application and try to call mRecorder.start() u have an illegal state. Possibly u don't release the MediaRecorder when your Activity pause.

Try with the next code:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    // if we are using MediaRecorder, release it first
    releaseMediaRecorder();
}

private void releaseMediaRecorder(){
    if (mMediaRecorder != null) {
        // clear recorder configuration
        mMediaRecorder.reset();
        // release the recorder object
        mMediaRecorder.release();
        mMediaRecorder = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try use, for 21-30 api it work

```
setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AAC_ADTS)
setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC)
```